# PyQide-Qt QSyntaxHighlighter multiline

Tags: qt, syntax-highlighting, pyside, qtextedit

The `highlightBlock(self, qtext)` of `QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter` treats each line in my `QTextEdit` widget as a different block (`qtext`). This brakes the **multiline flag** in my regular expression which is a deal-breaker in my situation! I read about the `setCurrentBlockState()` and `previousBlockState()` but they don't really help on not breaking the multiline flag.

Is there an easy way to overcome this that missed? And if not, Which you would propose as a best approach:

a) Extend `QTextEdit` and `QDocument` changing the QTextBlock from one line to the whole text.

b) Implement my own Highlighter with QTextLayout, QTextFormat etc from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with extending Qt classes (that are not advertised as extendable) is that a lot of methods are not virtual and furthermore, most of the implementation is done inside a [private](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/) class.

This makes extending not easy. So I would stick with plan B.